# vs-code extension doesn't Activate on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vs-code extension, I wrote a code for cron-jobs (runs extension at a certain time) and it works well. `the problem is my extension doesn't lunch at startup` I've read the docs and I did what I must do like I saw in docs and still doesn't work at startup.
`extension.ts:`

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import axios from "axios";
// dotenv
import "dotenv/config";

export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  var cron = require("node-cron");
  // API Call Goes Here...

 
  // *** Visual Studio Code ***
  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "myExtenstionIdAndNameNotForPublicXD",
    async () => {
      if (Content || Reference) {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
          `"${Content}" - ${Reference} `
        );
      } else {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
          `Network Error! `
        );
      }
      // *** Autostart ***
      {
        /*
    # ┌────────────── second (optional)
    # │ ┌──────────── minute
    # │ │ ┌────────── hour
    # │ │ │ ┌──────── day of month
    # │ │ │ │ ┌────── month
    # │ │ │ │ │ ┌──── day of week
    # │ │ │ │ │ │
    # │ │ │ │ │ │
    # * * * * * *
 */
      }
      cron.schedule(
        // S M H D M W
        "5 * * * * *",
        async () => {
          if (Content || Reference) {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
              `"${Content}" - ${Reference} `
            );
          } else {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
              `Network Error! `
            );
          }
        },
        {
          scheduled: true,
        }
      );
    }
  );

  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}
```

and here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "displayName": "name",
  "description": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.70.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": ["*"],
  "main": "./dist/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "name.name",
        "title": "name.name"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run package",
    "compile": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "package": "webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map",
    "compile-tests": "tsc -p . --outDir out",
    "watch-tests": "tsc -p . -w --outDir out",
    "pretest": "npm run compile-tests && npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts",
    "test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.56",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.70.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.31.0",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.5",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cron": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

- I need to auto-lunch the extension when the user opens vs code.
- then it shows a notification
- last, the cron-job code work well and push notifications daily (i know it will push every 15 sec .. just for test)

note: I get this error on my debug console
`Error: Unexpected SIGPIPE at process.<anonymous> (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/out-vscode/bootstrap.js:35:18) at process.emit (/home/kareem/Desktop/VerseOfTheDay-vscode/lib/events.js:390:28) at Signal.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {stack: 'Error: Unexpected SIGPIPE at process.<ano…Trampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)', message: 'Unexpected SIGPIPE'}`

that's it! `im sorry for hiding the extension name and details :)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that was not mentioned on DOCS,

You must do this next like this:
`extension.ts` or `extension.js`

```
  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
  // Solution is the next line after your context
  vscode.commands.executeCommand("identifier.yourExtensionName");
```

Also, make sure you have one of the following options on your `Package.json`

`"activationEvents": ["onStartupFinished"], // or "*"`

Ref: https://medium.com/secarmalabs/using-visual-studio-code-extensions-for-persistence-a65c940b7ea6
and
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events

I hope it helps you ^-^